# Search datetime in MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

I have a MySQL database, there's a table which have column Time's Type is **Nvachar(50)** and **its values** is **kind like this "05/09/2012 20:53:40:843"** **(Month-date-year hour:mins:second:msecond)**

Now I want to query to get a record have Time after "10/05/2012 01:00:30 PM".
I had code in C# to converted it to "05/10/2012 13:00:30" before making a query.
My Query :

```
SELECT * FROM ABCDFEGH WHERE capTime > '05/10/2012 13:00:30' LIMIT 0, 1
```

But i got no record. So please tell me how can I can make it return record have time after the time above ???

More Info My C# code :

```
string tableName = "ABCDFEGH";
string date = "05/10/2012 13:00:30";

var query = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE capTime > '" + date + "' LIMIT 0, 1";

var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
MySqlDataReader dataReader = null;
try
{
dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
}
```

I'm so so so so so so sorry. I made a mistake the query must be

```
SELECT * FROM ABCDFEGH WHERE capTime > '05/10/2012 13:00:30' LIMIT 0, 1
```

This query is successful return the record i need :)

But soemhow I have mistyped it into

```
SELECT * FROM ABCDFEGH WHERE capTime > '05-10-2012 13:00:30' LIMIT 0, 1
```

Sorry again, topic close. But tks for evveryone tried :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar can't you just comment nicely? why so many `!!!`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using the `DATETIME` datatype instead of NVARCHAR.  Store dates in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format, which is the [native DATETIME format recognized by MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html).

Also use date literals in the same format.

Two reasons for this recommendation:  First, [DATETIME takes only 8 bytes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-requirements.html), instead of up to 150 bytes which is the potential size of a multibyte 50 character varchar.

Second, the sort order of DATETIME will be the same as the chronological order.  So if you create an index on the `Time` column, your `>` comparison can benefit from the index.  Your query will be much faster as a result.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, yes I saw that this question is tagged `mysql`. My recommendation is intentional for MySQL.

Comment: `NVARCHAR` is not there in MySQL na?

Comment: @PraveenKumar, NVARCHAR is supported in MySQL as an alias for `VARCHAR CHARACTER SET utf8`.

Comment: I agree with you bill. Are you sure with that @PraveenKumar?

Answer (score 1):

#### Use `TIMESTAMPDIFF()`

#### Schema

```
CREATE TABLE ABCDFEGH (`right` varchar(3), `time` datetime);

INSERT INTO ABCDFEGH (`right`, `time`)
VALUES
    ('Yes', '2012-10-02 13:00:30'),
    ('No', '2012-10-15 13:00:30');
```

#### SQL Code

```
SELECT * FROM ABCDFEGH
  WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, time, '2012-10-05 13:00:30') > 0
  LIMIT 0, 1
```

#### Explanation

> [`TIMESTAMPDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) returns datetime_expr2 – datetime_expr1, where datetime_expr1 and datetime_expr2 are date or datetime expressions. One expression may be a date and the other a datetime; a date value is treated as a datetime having the time part '00:00:00' where necessary. The unit for the result (an integer) is given by the unit argument.

#### Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/244cc/1 `datetime`

#### Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/063b3/1 `varchar(50)`

***PS1:** `Time` may be a reserved word. Please avoid using it. Else use it with backticks (`).*

***PS2:** The format of time is `YYYY-MM-DD` not the reverse.*

Comment: Time is Column Name and the data type of this Column is Nvachar(50). Its values is kind like "05/09/2012 20:53:40:843"

Comment: Okay, updating the answer. Give me a min.

Comment: @BuiAkinori Can you check now?

Comment: I just used ur new answer and I got a list of this "Truncated incorrect datetime value: '04/13/2012 11:25:36:241'"

Comment: @BuiAkinori Have added the schema and the DDL.

Comment: @PraveenKumar the value format is `MM/dd/YYYY HH:mm:ss:sss` not `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` and it's NVARCHAR.

Comment: @JohnWoo **PLEASE READ THE QUESTION**. `NVARCHAR` is not there in MySQL and it is a MSSQL Datatype!!!

Comment: you have edited the question right? why didn't you also updated the tags?

Comment: @JohnWoo Updated the tags, removed `C#`

Comment: Oh, no no no, I code in C# and make a query to MySQL by Connectionstring to get record

Comment: @PraveenKumar why did you removed it? also `MYSQL` supports `NVARCHAR`. are you sure with what you are talking?

Answer (score 1):

First, why did you save the dates as `NVARCHAR`? If you are still able to change it to `DATETIME` datatype and all of the records on it, much better.

But if not, you can use `STR_TO_DATE`.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tableName
WHERE   STR_TO_DATE(`capTime`, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s:%x') > 
        STR_TO_DATE('05/10/2012 13:00:30', '%c/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s')
```

- [**See SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6441a/1)

SOURCES

- [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)
- [DATE Formats](http://davidwalsh.name/format-date-mysql-date_format)

**UPDATE 1**

and your query is vulnerable with `SQL Injection`. To avoid from it

- Parameterized your query

code snippet,

```
string tableName = "ABCDFEGH";
string date = "05/10/2012 13:00:30";
String query =  "SELECT  * FROM  " + tableName + " WHERE   STR_TO_DATE(`capTime`, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s:%x') >  STR_TO_DATE(@dateHere, '%c/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s')";
using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("connectionStringHere"))
{
    using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand())
    {
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = query;
        command.Parameters.AddwithValue("@dateHere",date)
        MySqlDataReader dataReader = null;
        try
        {
            dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        }
        catch(MySqlException e)
        {
            // do something here
            // don't suppress the error
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I try this and got a lot of  "Inccorect time value:'241' for function str_to_time' 241 is milisecond. Do u miss that part in ur query ?